# The problem of tool-related questions

Tags: discussion

The FAQ clearly states that one should not ask questions about code review tools or best-practices.

Yet, somehow I sense that *a lot* of questions about those topics are bound to be posted.

Now, from the user's point of view, seeing that I'm able to ask such a question tagging it `books`, `tools` or whatever, I might very well think I'm fully entitled to post it.
Because, as we know, users don't really read FAQs.

How about getting rid of tags designed for questions that are going to be closed anyway? Would that be too bad a thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions about these off-topic subjects have reduced *DRASTICALLY* since we set the policy and updated the FAQ, so I don't see this as a problem. Normally, the tags would be removed from the system automatically when those posts are deleted (this happens automatically). But I don't want to delete these posts posts outright, just yet. They provide a valuable signpost for new users as they become acclimated to this still-young site.

I *did* remove the tags manually and they should disappear from the system within a few days.

Answer (score 0):

that seems reasonable and will help towards discouraging those types of questions if that's what we're going for on this site.